# Symfony2 language switcher bundle default inclusion in base template

Tags: symfony, layout, include, bundle

I'm searching for a solution how I can implement a bundle into my base-template so that it will be visible on every page of my project without including it into every single Template/Bundle.

Is this possible? It's a language switch and I thought about building a bundle for it, so that it can interact directly to set the locale for all links etc...

Edit: Maybe I need to set it up as a service??

My problem is; how to get the language Selector into the base Template without any route ?

Answer (score 0):

So at least I figured out how to handle this. Maybe its not a beauty, but for now its working so that I can checkout a better solution

```
public function localize_route($locale = NULL) {
        // Merge query parameters and route attributes
        $attributes = array_merge($this->request->query->all(), $this->request->attributes->get('_route_params'));

        // Set/override locale
        $attributes['_locale'] = $locale ?: \Locale::getDefault();

        return $this->router->generate($this->request->attributes->get('_route'), $attributes);
    }
```

as it's described here http://blog.viison.com/post/15619033835/symfony2-twig-extension-switch-locale-current-route

So that it works